# OpenCVSharp MatchTemplate Masks

Tags: c#, opencv

I am currently trying to mask a object, both the template and mask are the same width/height same everything, In the current shared code I am literally using the same image for the template and mask and still getting the size error.

**Error**
OpenCvSharp.OpenCVException: '_templ.size() == _mask.size()'

**Code**

```
Mat tplMat = new Mat("c:\tmp\Image1.png", ImreadModes.Grayscale);
Mat tplMatMask = new Mat("c:\tmp\Image1mask.png", ImreadModes.Grayscale);
Mat refMat = new Mat("c:\tmp\test1.png", ImreadModes.Grayscale);
Mat res = new Mat();

Cv2.MatchTemplate(tplMat, refMat, res, TemplateMatchModes.CCoeffNormed, tplMat);
```

**Error on this line**
Cv2.MatchTemplate(tplMat, refMat, res, TemplateMatchModes.CCoeffNormed, tplMat);

Comment: Because it's `Cv2.MatchTemplate(refMat, tplMat, res, TemplateMatchModes.CCoeffNormed, tplMat);`, cf. [the source code](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/blob/ea7c67ff0df7b0bc003b46b245a413c7830ffb16/src/OpenCvSharp/Cv2/Cv2_imgproc.cs#L2585)

Comment: Thank you, i have no clue how i got the tmpl and ref backwards >.<